# Build fails sample Qt5 Unresolved symbol QtConcurrent QunhandledExecption

Tags: qt5, unhandled-exception, qtconcurrent, lnk2001

trying this sample code [qt-concurrent](https://%20https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html#using-member-functions), I am getting LNK2001 unresolved symbol QFutureInterfaceBase on link for x64 arch using MSVC 2019

> LNK2001   symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: void
> __cdecl QFutureInterfaceBase::reportException(class QException const &)"
> (_*imp*?reportException@QFutureInterfaceBase@@QEAAXAEBVQException@@@Z)
>
> LNK2001   symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public:
> virtual __cdecl QUnhandledException::~QUnhandledException(void)"
> (_*imp*??1QUnhandledException@@UEAA@XZ)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QtCore/QtCore>
#include <QtCore/QFuture> 
#include <QtCore/QUnhandledException>

#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent> 
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentRun> 
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentMap>


int main()
{
    // from https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html#using-member-functions
    QByteArray bytearray = "Hello World!";
    QFuture<QList<QByteArray> > future = QtConcurrent::run(bytearray, &QByteArray::split, ',');
    QList<QByteArray> result = future.result();
}
```

Here are my linked libs from directory C:\Qt\5.15.2\lib

> Qt5Concurrent.lib Qt5Core.lib Qt5Network.lib Qt5Sql.lib Qt5Widgets.lib
> Qt5Xml.lib

Note : When I checked Qt5Concurrent.dll it is well amd64 dll and so lib too.